# Unchecking Grant Users Exculsive Rights To

Tags: security, permissions, ntfs, folder-redirection

I set up my folder redirection with the "Grant Users Exclusive Rights to ..." checked. Now I'm trying to get to someone's AppData folder to fix a Firefox profile issue and I can't.

What I want to know: if I uncheck "Grant Users Exclusive Rights to ..." in my GPO and let it propegate, will that give administrators access to those folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it won't. That setting will only be applicable to new redirected folders, not existing redirected folders. For existing redirected folders you'll need to manually add the required permissions.